# Id as Name after creating new object

Tags: apex, custom-object

I created a custom object *Project__c*. I haven't added any custom fields to it yet. I have noticed something strange trying to insert new *Project__c* instance. I wrote this code:

```
Project__c newProject= new Project__c();
insert newProject;
```

and executed it. As a result I got new record with *Project Name: a0D58000001JeqC*. How is this possible? I was expecting error, because standard field *Project Name* is required.

Comment: Probably a convenience feature (not sure its documented) but I've noticed it too when writing unit tests.

Comment: I've seen it when doing data loads too where I don't care to export the name. You also see it all the time on change sets if anyone deploys using migration tools. I couldn't find any documentation of it either after a cursory search.

Comment: Does it mean I have to add validation rule to check if field Name is empty before insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't give a name through code, it defaults take it's ID.

The UI will require a user to input a String, but why does the code really need to force it to? The developer is the one creating the code and so then knows what should be acceptable.

For reference:[Standard field not throwing an error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36801/standard-name-field-required-from-standard-page-layout-but-not-from-apex-code)

Thanks dphil for nice explanation.